# Loop through many files and copy paste

Tags: excel, vba, match

I have a main file that looks like this. Sheet is called "Paylist".

```
     A        B
1    ID     Value
2   2902    
3   2928    
4   1777    
5   2707    
6   2746    
7   1224    
8   2068    
9   2937    
10  2709    
11  2903    
12  2579    
13  2926
```

I want to bring the value (column B) corresponding to each ID.
This can be brought from many files (all looking the same), as there is a separate file for each ID. In this files, the ID is found always on cell "D5" and the Value on cell "F19', 1st worksheet.

So I have to loop through each sheet, copy cell value "F19" and then paste it in the main file, on the row where the IDs in both files match.

I know how to loop through files.

How do I paste to the right cell and how do I switch between the main file and the other ones?

Here is the code that I have. My idea was to try to find the row number where I should paste the value using Match. I am having difficulties switching between the files and I don't want to limit the main file to a certain name, as it won't always be the same.

```
Sub Paylist()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim LastRow As Long, lastcolumn As Long
Dim eRow As Long

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xls"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Copy cell F19

    wb.Worksheets(1).Range("F19").Copy
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Paste values - I know this is really bad here, but I think you get the idea of what I wanted to do

    eRow = MATCH(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("D5"),R1C1:R2500C1,0)

    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Paylist").Cells(eRow, 2)

    'Close Workbook
    wb.Close

    'Get next file name
    myFile = Dir
Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please share where are you going wrong?

Comment: Also have some clarifications.I was very confused a lot. Sorry for that. I understood that you want to fill in the Values in Column B of Sheet "Palylist". Now here are my clarifications. From which sheet and cell he value to be placed in the Column will be fetched from? and the Id logic also.

Answer (score 0):

If Your Playlist sheet is from different workbook, then you need to Activate the Workbook before you paste it.

```
wb.Worksheets(1).Activate
wb.Worksheets(1).Range("F19").Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks("UrPlaylistSheetWorkbook").Sheets("Playlist").Activate  
eRow = MATCH(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("D5"),R1C1:R2500C1,0)
Cells(eRow, 2).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Hi Siva, so I have the main workbook, where I want to bring that value to column B, according to the ID. Each ID has its own workbook, where besides other stuff, has this value, that I have to bring to the main workbook. So I have the main workbook and like 10 workbooks, all the same format, from each workbook, I can bring the value for just one ID. So basically I have to go through each file, match the ID with the one in the main file and copy on column B next to that ID. 

For first, the erow that I set-up seems to not be correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input.

I am again confused in switching through the files.
So: I activate the source file, I copy the value.
I activate the main file - Problem here is that the main file needs to always have that name, and it won't be the same everytime I use it.
then I create the erow - Problem here is that the D5 is from the source file, while the range where it's looking is from the main file...

I don't really know how to explain, I hope you understand....

Comment: Do you mean to say that the name of  main workbook in which column B to be updtaed changes? You need to Look for the D5 value(i.e., ID) in main file ID's and then paste the F19 value in cell next to the ID. Am i right in my Understanding?

Comment: Yes, it's not always the same. Your understanding is correct. Just one main file. But a lot of other files (sources) from which I take the value. Each file has the Value for just one ID.

Can you access this link? https://www.dropbox.com/s/0a0ij0ctxkiw5th/Files.7z?dl=0

I put the files in there so you can have a better understanding.

Again, thank you so much for your efforts, much appreciated!

Comment: You have one main file let's Say varXYZ, and multiple sources S1,S2... varXYX name keeps changing. From which workbook you want to run the macro

Comment: From the main one. (varXYZ). And then make a loop through each source. So: select a folder where I have all sources, then Open S1, copy the value from S1 to varXYZ, close S1. Open S2, copy the value from S2 to varXYZ, close S2 and so on...that's my idea.

Comment: So your varXYZ, remains same throught the code, then what do you mean by changes?

Comment: For identifying the ID in varXYZ, I recommend use .Find so that the row number can be found easily. But only when ID are unique

Comment: It is. But I solved it probably in a stupid way. But it works. Basically, in the source file I concatenated the ID and Value, copy that in a random column in the main file, then did the work right there: split the column into two (ID and Value) and then with vlookup bring the value. then delete that random column.